# Why isn't the Thevenin equivalent impedance calculated as a function of frequency?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, thevenin

When I look for calculations of Thevenin equivalent circuits, the equivalent impedance, \$Z_{th}\$, is always calculated with the frequency at which the source operates in all the examples I can find. Now, I understand that we use the equivalent circuit to be able to plug in any circuit we want between the points of the circuit for which we calculated the equivalent, but those calculations restrict \$Z_{th}\$ to a certain frequency. Why can't I work out \$Z_{th}\$ as a function of frequency?

Comment: Why can't you? Try taking one of these circuits with real impedances and change them to general complex variable impedances, and then solve for \$Z_{th}\$. Your title question is misleading, since by definition having a \$Z_{th}\$ as a function of frequency is synonymous with a frequency-dependent "Thevenin's theorem."

Comment: I already did it. With the help of a computational software. OK, I'll change the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impedance of capacitors and inductors is frequency dependent. You can express Zth as a function of frequency but to calculate it **for a particular example** you need to know the frequency.

Comment: "for a particular example" you mean the particular source for which you calculate the equivalent? What I meant was, given a particular source, \$V(t)\$ in that circuit, if you calculate the impedance with the frequency of \$V(t)\$, I understand that you can't plug in any other frequency, or else, the calculation you made for the equivalent impedance is not useful anymore. I mean, in that case, the equivalent impedance should be as a function of frequency in order to be useful.

Comment: Yes you need to be able to plug your particular source frequency into your frequency dependent function in order to get a calculated numeric answer. I am differentiating between writing a function and calculating the result of that function for a particular set of inputs.

Comment: If that is the case, then why in every example I find on the Internet, the \$Z_{th}\$ is calculated at the frequency of the circuit you're calculating the equivalent for? I haven't found any example in which \$Z_{th}\$ is left as a function of frequency.

Comment: Or maybe I haven't explain myself quite well and you're confused about my question.

Comment: I think we are arguing semantics here if you want to calculate Zth you need to know the frequency. This does not stop you from writing a mathematical function for Zth in terms of Capacitance Inductance Resistance and frequency.

Comment: No, I'm not arguing that. Suppose I have an AC circuit with a source \$V (t)\$ with certain frequency \$f_{1}\$, and capacitors and inductors anywhere in the circuit. By Thevenin's theorem, I can substitute all that circuit between two points by the equivalent impedance, \$Z_{th}\$, and a source equivalent to the voltage difference between the two points. Now, if I calculate \$Z_{th}\$, as it is done, and I plug in to the equivalent a circuit at \$f_{2} \neq f_{1}\$, I can't use \$Z_{th}\$ for \$f_{2}\$. With \$Z_{th}\$ as a function of frequency I could solve the circuit with superposition.

Comment: I thought that is what I just said.

Answer (score 0):

Who says you can't or that nobody does?

Here's a figure from the datasheet of a randomly selected op-amp:

[image]

Similar figures are generally provided for any IC where users are likely to need this information to be able to use the IC.

If it would be interesting information for users of a circuit you design, by all means, calculate or measure its thevenin equivalent impedance as a function of frequency.

Comment: It's an assignment for a first course in electronics from college. Most of the people I have talked to are doing it wrong and I thought it made more sense this way but I couldn't find any information. People are very hostile here to some questions...

Comment: @kdow So this question is actually from an assignment? It didn't cross my mind before now. Are you wanting \$Z_{th\left(\omega\right)}\$, then?

Comment: The assignment consists in calculating the Thevenin equivalent circuit of some AC circuit. And we have to figure out how to do it. And yes, that's what makes sense to me but it's difficult to find good examples.

Comment: @jonk Sorry, I think because I didn't put this thing jonk wasn't notified about the comment.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks! Too bad I can't go back and edit that. My head was working towards the \$\frac{-j}{\omega C}\$ and I mis-wrote. Again, thanks for the catch. Oh. never mind. I can delete it!!

Comment: @kdow (Newly edited version) Okay. That's pretty easy. Just do the usual but use \$R\$, \$\frac{−j}{\omega C}\$, and \$j \omega L\$ for your impedances when you do the usual things. Then solve for the standard form complex result. You can plug in any \$\omega\$ you want, later on. But you have your answer, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If one is interested in the behavior of an RLC network at one particular frequency, one can compute the impedance of each component or subsection at that frequency as a complex number and then use complex arithmetic to compute the equivalent impedance of combinations of them, until at the end one has managed to reduce all the complexity to a single impedance.

Although the formulas would continue to work if one treated the frequency as a parameter rather than treating it as a constant, they would not in general be amenable to reduction.  If e.g. one takes 50 0.1uf capacitors and wires a different value of resistor in parallel with each, and wires all 50 RC pairs in series, one could compute the total impedance of the string by adding the impedance of all 50 pairs.  At any given frequency, the impedance of each pair will be a (complex) number and consequently the total impedance of the string will likewise be a (complex) number.  Further, if all of the resistors had been identical, one could produce a convenient parametric formula because the terms involving the frequency parameter would all have been identical and the total impedance would thus be 50 times the impedance of one RC pair.  If the resistors are different, however, the impedance of each pair will involve the frequency in a slightly different way, and so the total impedance will have 50 terms that cannot be consolidated.